# On injectivity of a special function

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

Consider map $f$:
$$ f:(1,+\infty)^2\longrightarrow P(\mathbb{N}^2)\\ 
f(x,y):=\{\ (n,m)\in \mathbb{N}^2\quad |\ x^n < y^m  \ \} $$
The question is that whether $f$ is injective or not.It must be injective but 
I don't have any idea to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(1,2)=\mathbb{N}^2 = f(1,3)$, so $f$ is not injective.

**Edit:** The codomain of $f$ was changed into $(1,+\infty)$. In this case, $f$ is still not injective as $f(2,4) = f(3,9) = \{(m,n) \in \mathbb{N}^2: n>2m\}$.

Comment: ok. I just edit my question.sorry for it's mistake.

Comment: if it's domain changes to $(2,4)$ what we can say? Thanks for your attention.